# match files in unordered file with grep

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep

How do I match only file names in an unordered file with grep?

I tried `grep -Po '[a-zA-Z1-9/_-]{1,}\.php'` ( I am trying to match php files),
but that doesn't work for e.g `http://www.google.com/index.php`, because it matches `com/index.php`. It also needs to catch things like `/directory/subdirectory/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6}))?([^\s]+\.php)
```

example:

```
my text http://www.google.com/index.php /bla.php my end
```

result: "http://www.google.com/index.php" and "/bla.php"